# Postgresql query gives less results for wider search

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing a very wierd issue where query.

My query is very complax so I'll use a simpler version of it.

```
select distinct on (a.batch) c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock_stock,
from components a 
join parts b using(partid)
left join (select * from componentsreport($1)) c using (partid)
JOIN start_work d on d.batchid=a.batchid
where  b.issub
group by c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock
order by a.batch;
```

This query gives many rows but only 1 row for `c.id=3436`:

```
3436 124  'CPU-A' 450
```

However when I add another criteria `c.id=3436` :

```
select distinct on (a.batch) c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock_stock,
from components a 
join parts b using(partid)
left join (select * from componentsreport($1)) c using (partid)
JOIN start_work d on d.batchid=a.batchid
where  c.id=3436 and b.issub
group by c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock
order by a.batch;
```

I get 6 rows:

```
3436 124  'CPU-A' 450
3436 125  'CPU-A' 130
3436 125  'CPU-A' 660
3436 126  'CPU-A' 0
3436 127  'CPU-A' 40
3436 128  'CPU-A' 40
```

Which is correct!

I don't understand how when I add more conditions I get more rows? It looks like something is bugged!

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.3

Please advise what may cause this problem.

Comment: Inference on `c.` in: `where  c.id=3436` will reduce your LEFT JOIN TO a plain join.

Comment: @wildplasser It doesn't matter. inner join gives same results in both cases.

Comment: That's what I said. LEFT JOIN makes no sense if you are forcing c.id to a fixed value.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `left join (select * from componentsreport($1)) c` can be simplified to `left join componentsreport($1) c`

Answer (score 0):

This is correct result. The reason, you have no `group by a.batch`, only distinct.

F.ex. you have following data:

```
c.id = 3436, a.batch = 1
c.id = 3436, a.batch = 2
c.id = 3437, a.batch = 1
c.id = 3437, a.batch = 2
```

Select distinct after group and order will gave you 1 unique batch = `1`

select with where will gave you 2 unique a.batch: `1`, `2`.

So, to fix this query you need wrap first variant of select to another one with condition.

```
select * 
from (
   select distinct on (a.batch) c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock_stock,
   from components a 
      join parts b using(partid)
      left join (
         select * 
         from componentsreport($1)
      ) c using (partid)
      JOIN start_work d on d.batchid=a.batchid
   where  b.issub
   group by c.id,a.partid,b.partname,c.stock
   order by a.batch
) tmp 
where tmp.id = 3436
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what I need to do.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The inner query still produce 1 row, so the otter query won't get u more.

Comment: To understand a problem try to execute query without distinct.

Comment: Also, could you prepare some sandbox or schema, data to allow us check it too.